# Getting the value of a returned string from Ajax JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a web service which adds an item to the database after being called using JQuery Ajax. The web service returns a string, and I can't manage to pick up only the string part returned. Instead I receive `{"d":"The message I want to display"}` using `alert(data);`.

I also `tried alert(Object.keys(JSON.parse(data))[0]);` which returns `d` and `alert(Object.keys(JSON.parse(data))[1]);` or `alert(data.d);`  returns `Undefined`.Here's what my code looks like

```
function AddAjaxJQuery() {
            var isbn = $('#<%= txtIsbn.ClientID %>').val();

            var pdata = { "book": { "Isbn": isbn} };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "/BookWebService.asmx/InsertBook",
                data: JSON.stringify(pdata),
                dataType: 'text',
                async: true,
                success: function (data, textStatus) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data is a string, then you should parse it to JSON first:

```
var dataInJson = JSON.parse(data);
alert(dataInJson.d)
```

Comment: Yes, it returns `Undefined` using `alert(data.d);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to access property `d` of data (response) so Replace success callback with

```
success: function (data, textStatus) {
    alert(data.d);
},
```